# Explicit old fashioned error handling in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2

Apple introduced fancy new error handling in Swift 2

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID10

I'm working with project that uses AFNetoworking v2.x where AFHTTPRequestSerializer has 2 selectors:

```
- (NSMutableURLRequest *)requestWithMethod:(NSString *)method
                             URLString:(NSString *)URLString
                            parameters:(id)parameters DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE;

- (NSMutableURLRequest *)requestWithMethod:(NSString *)method
                             URLString:(NSString *)URLString
                            parameters:(id)parameters
                                 error:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error;
```

First is deprecated but second is converted automatically to first signature by Swift 2 compiler. Old fashioned method now doesn't allowed:

```
var error: NSError?
let request = self!.operationManager.requestSerializer.requestWithMethod(method, URLString: url?.absoluteString, parameters: params, error: error)
```

gives me a compile time error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'NSError?' to expected argument type '()'
```

But brand new notation reduces selector with error processing to deprecated variant without it.

```
do {
    let request = try
    self!.operationManager.requestSerializer.requestWithMethod(method, URLString: url?.absoluteString, parameters: params)
} catch let error as NSError {
    // ...
}
```

What is best practice in Swift 2 to solve this problem? Is there any way to specify certain selector in this situation?

UPD: More precise link on Swift 2 feature that become a reason of my problem. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID10

Comment: Well, I know what I would do; I'd write a trampoline method in Objective-C. (And I'd file a bug report with the AFNetworking people.)

Comment: Yes it looks like a better choice in case Swift 2 have no tools to solve this itself. But I wonder Swift architects predicted such problems and they had some proper way in minds to overcome this type of problems.

Comment: Are you sure the deprecated variant is called? Maybe Xcode just mixes up deprecation warnings?

Answer (score 0):

Seems this works properly in Xcode 7.1 (I recall having this issue in 7.0) just change your method to use an error pointer i.e `&error`

```
var error: NSError?
let request = self!.operationManager.requestSerializer.requestWithMethod(method, URLString: url?.absoluteString, parameters: params, error: &error)
```

Comment: I haven't updated my Xcode yet. I'll try it with Xcode 7.1. Hope this helps. Thank you!

Comment: I still having error for this code after updating to Xcode 7.1: "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments"

Comment: @lazarev are you wrapping it in a `do {} catch {}` block? Just tested again without `do catch` and it seems to compile fine. Will you post the code you're using and version of `AFNetworking`

Comment: That strange. Here simplified version still having the problem:
https://gist.github.com/lazarev/127e27f6bc235338fcbd

As for version that's my another problem. I received project with lots of dependencies mixed with codebase without any dependency control solution. I just can't determine exact version. But according copyright dates (2015) in of some files it should be at least 2.5.1.

Comment: @lazarev you need to use an error pointer change `error` to `&error` the code example you posted still isn't using a pointer.

Comment: Oh yes. You are right. I forgot about this. But in this case I have this error: `'&' used with non-inout argument of type '()'`

Here in blog post I've found the same situation:
http://www.pixeldock.com/blog/how-to-pass-an-error-pointer-to-a-function-in-swift/

But error message are different: `'&' used with non-inout argument of type 'NSErrorPointer' (aka 'AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer>')`

Looks like in my case compiler don't understand type of this parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Swift 2 prefers to provide Try Catch block to necessary methods only. Thus if your method have cases where you might need error handling then only provide this block.

```
do {    
   try managedObjectContext.save() 
} catch {

   // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

   // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

   let NSError = error as NSError

   NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
   abort()
}
```

Comment: Actually I had to provide more precise link about this mechanism. I put it on the bottom.

I understand how to handle errors in Swift 2. But Swift 2 automatically change old style selectors from Objective C. And this "feature" may produce selectors that conflicts with other selectors as I show in my example.

I just don't know what to do in this case.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID10